# How to make two buttons on different pages do the same thing in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, button, xamarin.forms

I have two pages, **HomePage** and **FoundPage**. I have a button called *SearchButton* on HomePage and another button called *MoreButton* on FoundPage. I already have coded what I'd like the program to do when SearchButton is clicked.

So in **HomePage.xaml** I have this and it works well:

```
<Button x:Name="SearchButton"
        Clicked="SearchButton_OnClicked"/>
```

I would like to use the same SearchButton_OnClicked in **FoundPage.xaml**, so I tried this, but obviously, it didn't work:

```
<Button x:Name="MoreButton"
        Clicked="SearchButton_OnClicked"/>
```

Is there any way I can transfer it to use it in **FoundPage.xaml** as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can either copy paste the `SearchButton_OnClicked` code in `FoundPage.xaml.cs` 
or create a common backend in a class and use it from there

Comment: I have some items in HomePage.xaml (e.g. a Label) which I use in SearchButton_OnClicked, so I guess I need it to be in HomePage.xaml.cs. Is the backend still a solution in this case? And if yes, could you tell me how I have to do that? I'm beginner, sorry if this question is a little dumb.

Comment: You can either place the label in FoundPage as well or use a public string and save there the content of HomePage Label to use it in FoundPage too.